# What should I do if my question was close voted without correct reasons?

Tags: discussion, moderators, close-reasons, closed-questions

I have asked a genuine [question](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/2968/can-garuda-puranam-be-read-at-home) which I had in mind. Unfortunately it was marked as duplicate by one of the moderators because the moderator had posted a similar question. I did my due research looking into the portal and I also quoted his question for reference.

I believe this is not a duplicate and the questions are different. Now the question is marked duplicate, how can I request for some one else to review and provide sufficient details based on their discretion.

Comment: I'll rollback your post with minor edits else my answer will become irrelevant to your question, so don't edit your post now, I'll take over from here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's nothing to panic if a user close voted your question. Lets assume that he close voted unknowingly or say he is not sure of how to use his privileges so whats the best you can do is post a comment to the user saying that the question may be related but not duplicate so please retract your close vote.

If the user doesn't retract his close vote, then the vote will expire at certain point automatically by the system (I'll share a link for this feature soon). Am sure you must be seeing a notice above your question explaining that you might find answers on X question but its only visible to you and not others.

For some reason if your questions gets closed, and you think it was not fair, feel free to flag your question and ask for moderators help, we will reopen your post if the close votes are not justified.

Also, it takes 5 votes for the users to close your question, so if other users are wise enough to judge that the question is not a duplicate, they will not cast a close vote.

> Note: The user is **not** a moderator, [there are only three
>   moderators on the site](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users?tab=moderators). If a moderator casts a close vote, it
>   will close your question immediately. The user is having privileges
>   to [cast close and reopen votes](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It gives me more clarity. It more a concern than panic.

Comment: @karthikbharadwaj Don't worry, if you are sure that thing is wrong feel free to flag and notify the moderator and explain him whats wrong else you can post on meta if you want community inputs over any issue.

Comment: I did the same.Thanks for the info and guidelines