# Notify OP in inbox, when people close vote a question

Tags: feature-request, closed-questions, vote-to-close, notifications

I find it creepy that you put your question out there and as it percolates downwards due to newer questions, people maybe voting to close it, unbeknownst to you.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What should I do if my question was close voted without correct reasons?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/313/what-should-i-do-if-my-question-was-close-voted-without-correct-reasons)

Comment: this is not about whether the reasons are correct.  all reasons except obvious things like profanity are incorrect.  the question is about process - someone needs to be notified for each vote to close their question or at least if and when it gets closed.

Comment: First, Stack Exchange is _not_ a Democracy. We will be notified when it is voted to close as duplicate, But for other reasons, we have to keep track of what is happening with our question. It is _our_  question after all ;) . This is a proposal which should be discussed on network level and [was asked already](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/357396) for close reasons. Adding for vote to close would be bad because they can be false positives too.

Comment: I find that annoying too.  Sometimes I only find out that one of my questions has been closed months after the fact (especially on SE sites I don't visit that much).  But this is a network-wide feature of the system, so this question is better asked on Main Meta.SE.

Answer (score 2):

Following thread discussed your concern:
[Send authors an inbox message if their question is put on hold](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/93842/163449)

Several commentators and answers agree that, there is a need to notify the OP about the [possible] closure of the question.

Comment: thanks.  no censorrship is best but given that there is censorship it can at least be respectful and transparent @iammind